# Analytics reports are empty

Tags: 2013, analytics

I'm trying to troubleshot missing data in web analytics reports.

I've made a couple of diagnostics and here's what I noted:

- WSS_Usage database is populated. I can see in this DB recent updates
- MySearchApp_AnalyticsDB however, is empty

What else can I check ?